# How can I invoke my codesGenerator function again?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I wrote pass generator where you can type into input field how many letter should be in the generated password.

After clicking GeneratePasswords button function creates divs with passwords.
There is a Reset button which clears all generated passwords/divs and value from input field.

But when I click Reset I can not invoke codesGenerator function again and generate my new passwords.

I really got stuck with it.

```
const signs = 'aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPrRsStTuUwWxXyYzZ0123456789';
const btn = document.getElementById('generate');
const reset = document.getElementById('reset');
const section = document.querySelector('section');
const codeNumber = 3; // number of generated codes
let signNumbers = document.getElementById('signNumbers'); // number of signs in each code


const codesGenerator = () => {
    if (signNumbers.value > 0 && signNumbers.value < 25 && signNumbers !== NaN) {
        for (let i = 0; i < codeNumber; i++) { // how many codes to generate - loop
            let code = '';
            for (let j = 0; j < signNumbers.value; j++) { // how many signs in each code - loop
                const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * signs.length);
                code += signs[index];
            }

            const div = document.createElement('div');
            div.textContent = code;
            section.appendChild(div);
        }
    }
}

const resetAll = () => {
    signNumbers.value = '';
    section.remove();
}

btn.addEventListener('click', codesGenerator);
reset.addEventListener('click', resetAll);
```

Comment: `section.remove();` -> `section.appendChild(div);` should give you a clue. (Hint: Open up your browser console with F12). You are trying to append to an element you removed.

Comment: Thanx Icecub, I used removeChild(div).Now I have another issue but will try to fix it.